# Why is a system sending "ICMP time exceeded in-transit" messages when forwarding packets?

Tags: networking, ip-forwarding

I have the following setup

```
| laptop A connected via Wireguard to a server - 192.168.20.3 |
  
| server B with Wireguard (192.168.20.0) and connected to a LAN (192.168.10.2). Forwarding is enabled |
  
| server C connected to LAN (192.168.10.3) |
```

The routing table on `B` is:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp3s0 proto static
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-4f4174b6b888 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2
192.168.20.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.0
192.168.20.3 dev wg0 proto static
```

I am trying to ping `C` from `A` (`A` pinging `B` is OK). The ping fails.

When watching the traffic on `B`, I see

```
# tcpdump -i any -nn icmp
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:10:39.232603 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 157, length 72
14:10:39.232658 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 100
14:10:39.240944 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 158, length 72
14:10:39.240983 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 100
14:10:39.248667 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 159, length 72
```

The first packet (in) is the `ICMP echo request` sent from `A` to `C` (via `B`)
The second packet (out) should be `B` forwarding to `C`

**What does the `ICMP time exceeded in-transit` mean in this case?**

---

**EDIT**

I rebooted the server `B` and now the ping is fine. It is still very weird, though. Below is a single session of a ping from `A` to `C`, as seen on `B`:

```
PS C:\Users\X> tracert -d 192.168.10.3

Tracing route to 192.168.10.3 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     6 ms     6 ms     8 ms  192.168.20.0
  2     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  192.168.10.3



root@srv ~# tcpdump -i any -nn icmp
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
15:01:39.235308 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 180, length 72
15:01:39.235355 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 100
15:01:39.243813 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 181, length 72
15:01:39.243854 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 100
15:01:39.251044 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 182, length 72
15:01:39.251075 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 100
15:01:39.783426 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP host 192.168.10.188 unreachable, length 82
15:01:39.783455 wg0   Out IP 192.168.20.0 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP host 192.168.10.188 unreachable, length 82
15:01:40.262055 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 183, length 72
15:01:40.262083 enp3s0 Out IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 183, length 72
15:01:40.262509 enp3s0 In  IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 183, length 72
15:01:40.262530 wg0   Out IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 183, length 72
15:01:40.270041 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 184, length 72
15:01:40.270068 enp3s0 Out IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 184, length 72
15:01:40.270423 enp3s0 In  IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 184, length 72
15:01:40.270440 wg0   Out IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 184, length 72
15:01:40.278474 wg0   In  IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 185, length 72
15:01:40.278493 enp3s0 Out IP 192.168.20.3 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 185, length 72
15:01:40.278829 enp3s0 In  IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 185, length 72
15:01:40.278842 wg0   Out IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.3: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 185, length 72
```

It takes a few packets with `ICMP time exceeded in-transit` to finally have correct traffic go through.

---

Note: this is the "to" route of the packet, the "reply" one will go through `C`'s default gateway that knows the route for `192.168.20.0/24`

Comment: Check the firewall. Paste the output of `iptables-save -c`.

Comment: Off-topic, but what is the character in the second line of the first code block? FF can't display it.

Comment: @AntonDanilov: there is no firewall (except on the ISP box where the port is forwarded to the Wireguard server). One the tunnel is established there is no firewall.

Comment: @Paul this is a unicode Downwards Arrow (https://unicode-table.com/en/1F817/). Maybe in the comments section you will see it better: 

Comment: Check the `ip route get <C-ip> from <A-ip> iif wg0` and vise versa on B host. Add `-v` option to `tcpdump` command to display the original TTL value in ip packets.

Answer (score 1):

`ICMP time exceeded in-transit` means that the TTL of the packet reached zero, most probably due to a routing loop.

Comment: Yes, I know the technical reason for the message - it is just that I do not see here any loop in routing (`traceroute` stops at the first hop for instance)